# Соответствие меток между англо- и русскоязычной версиями StackOverflow

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, метки, синонимы-меток

Вот ссылка на поиск вопросов с метками `java` и `string` на английском языке

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+string

Если в начале этой ссылки просто добавить `ru.`, тоесть сделать её такой:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+string

то произойдёт редирект на

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8

то есть метка `string` будет автоматически преобразована в `строки`.

Тут есть небольшой баг: плюс в ссылке будет заменён на пробел, но похоже, что это работает правильно и так, хотя хорошо бы тоже исправить.

Однако если изначальная ссылка такая:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+arrays

то после добавления `ru.` редирект не произойдёт и адрес страницы останется

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+arrays

и вот эта ссылка уже неправильная (результатов поиска - ноль), потому что метка `arrays` в зоне `ru.` не существует и не переводится. А вот если заменить `arrays` на `array` в этой ссылке, то есть сделать её такой

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+array

То произойдёт редирект на:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b

И вот так оно уже работает: `array` переводится в `массивы` и результат поиска ненулевой.

Могут ли админы русскоязычного StackOverflow исправить оба бага?

Comment: Составляй полный список.

Comment: @Qwertiy с arrays можно действительно добавить синоним, чтоб ссылка заработала

Comment: Замена плюса на %20 - это не баг. Оба варианта являются представлениями пробела при url-кодировании.

Answer (score 3):

Это не то, чтобы баг. По-моему, нет никакой договорённости в плане меток между сайтами.

[string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) заменяется на [строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8), т.к. у нас это [синонимы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/synonyms), а основной выбрано `строки`. Тут, в общем-то, всё правильно.

По поводу же [array](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array)...Метки создаются по мере использования. Раз нет метки [arrays](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), значит её никто не используется. Максимум, что можно сделать - добавить её как [синоним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B/synonyms) к [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b).

Comment: Думаю, что лучше добавить. А что насчёт пробела вместо плюса?

Comment: @РостиславКрасный этот плюс ни на что не влияет. Он игнорируется. Он работает на странице поиска только https://stackoverflow.com/search